# userIdentity.AddClaim Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-identity

Is there a way to allow the values to be null?,("FullName + Website). Since they are strings i do not understand why it cannot be null. Anyone care to explain and show me how to solve, the issue im having?

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FullName", FullName));
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("Website", Website));
        return userIdentity;
    }

}
```

This is the way i use the data.

```
 public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    public static string GetFullName(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        if (identity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");
        }
        var ci = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (ci != null)
        {
            return ci.FindFirstValue("FullName");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static string GetWebsite(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        if (identity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("identity");
        }
        var ci = identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (ci != null)
        {
            return ci.FindFirstValue("Website");
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

razor:

```
 <input class="form-control" value="@User.Identity.GetFullName()">
```

Comment: Go debug your application. Breakpoint in `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` method and see values for both of `Fullname` and `Website`. One of them is null.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, `Claim` does not allow to null value to be inserted. Instead you can use an empty string.